# Query columns from multiple tables filtered by date time in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have many tables (values****m) in postgres with data averaged over roughly 1 min:

`select * from values0049m;`

```
             stamp             |   min    |    avg     |   max    | count |    sd_pop     |    sd_samp
-------------------------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------------
 2022-02-02 15:30:33.919115+00 |  7.28899 |  7.2962117 |  7.30366 |    26 |    0.00296413 |  0.0030228314
 2022-02-02 15:31:29.311468+00 |   7.2929 |  7.2962756 |  7.30403 |    32 |  0.0028273817 |  0.0028726228
 2022-02-02 15:32:29.675871+00 |  7.29511 |  7.2984433 |  7.30009 |    31 |  0.0014812931 |  0.0015057789
 2022-02-02 15:33:32.6375+00   |  7.29854 |  7.2997017 |  7.30026 |    16 |  0.0003772721 | 0.00038964496
 2022-02-02 15:34:30.110312+00 |  7.29874 |   7.299728 |  7.30104 |    32 | 0.00055568543 | 0.00056457694
 2022-02-02 15:35:29.49+00     |  7.29904 |   7.299784 |  7.30061 |    30 |  0.0004737743 | 0.00048187358
 2022-02-02 15:36:30.436818+00 |  7.29877 |  7.2993784 |  7.29992 |    33 | 0.00030168038 |  0.0003063579
 2022-02-02 15:37:30.791129+00 |  7.29763 |  7.2990456 |  7.29994 |    31 | 0.00049594446 | 0.00050414243
 2022-02-02 15:38:29.959225+00 |  7.29799 |  7.2986465 |  7.29953 |    31 |  0.0004001316 |  0.0004067458
 2022-02-02 15:39:28.726903+00 |  7.29755 |   7.298287 |  7.29928 |    31 | 0.00045724952 | 0.00046480788
 2022-02-02 15:40:30.48475+00  |  7.29736 |   7.298089 |  7.29869 |    32 | 0.00033257954 | 0.00033790115
 2022-02-02 15:41:30.76053+00  |  7.29682 |  7.2974124 |  7.29789 |    32 | 0.00025893928 | 0.00026308256
 2022-02-02 15:42:31.968741+00 |  7.29589 |  7.2970934 |  7.29768 |    31 | 0.00038452385 | 0.00039088004
```

I want to make a query that takes the avg data column from each table and takes every value/row between two defined time points. So I end up with a table that has stamp (time), avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4 and so on. A little bit like this:

`SELECT a.stamp as time, a.avg as pH_A, b.avg as pH_B FROM values0049m a, values0032m b WHERE a.stamp = b.stamp;`

```
             time              |   ph_a    |   ph_b
-------------------------------+-----------+-----------
 2022-02-06 00:37:29.867968+00 |  8.076844 |  8.034792
 2022-03-02 09:09:57.4595+00   | 7.3978453 |  7.397835
 2022-03-03 14:18:16.081+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:21:17.08+00     |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-04-10 20:00:35.4345+01   |    8.2415 |  8.284345
 2022-02-07 15:01:57.0825+00   |   7.19762 |   7.19723
 2022-02-23 20:04:30.594201+00 | 12.241002 | 7.3871346
 2022-02-23 22:09:30.140313+00 | 12.181907 | 7.3888736
 2022-03-03 14:13:15.069+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:14:15.073+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:15:15.601+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:16:16.067+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:17:16.078+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:19:16.578+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-03-03 14:20:16.581+00    |   7.41133 |   7.39908
 2022-04-10 19:59:05.426+01    |   8.24082 |   8.28444
(16 rows)
```

Whatever combination of `JOIN` that I use, it only gives me rows where the columns match (like the above) and doing below seems to create an infinite loop:

`SELECT a.stamp as time, a.avg as pH_A, b.avg as pH_B FROM values0049m a, values0032m b;`

I just cant seem to find a solution for this simple problem! (I am completely new to SQL)

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated, TIA!

Comment: You have to round off the time portion of the timestamp to hh:mm , and then join the tables. Datepart(hour, tstamp), datepart(min,tstamp) or use `extract`

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you want ?

```
SELECT 
  MIN(stamp) AS time, 
  to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch from stamp))) AS p
FROM values0049m a
  UNION ALL
SELECT 
  MIN(stamp), 
  to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch from stamp)))
FROM values0032m b;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3bae57187c0eb11d2c05e98d2f156db2)*

Comment: The following error is produced: ERROR:  function avg(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT MIN(stamp) AS time, avg(stamp) AS p
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Sorry - I've corrected - it should work now

Comment: No need for apologies, I am very grateful for your input. With the amendment, the output is the minimum time in the first column and the avg time for all time (time starts around Feb 2021 up till ```now()```.   
```             time              |               p
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2022-02-02 15:30:33.919115+00 | 2022-03-08 19:54:43.918857+00
 2022-02-02 15:30:34.129851+00 | 2022-03-08 19:54:34.622885+00
(2 rows)```